# Emulate textbox behavior using span

Tags: textbox, html

let's i have the following code http://jsfiddle.net/QhJWt/

```
<span contentEditable="true">asdfasdf </span>
span
{
    height:20px; 
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

how can i emulate textbox behavior? i.e. when text longer then span width it doesnt resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:block` to your `span` element, because `inline` elements ignore `width` and `height` properties. Then, add `word-wrap: break-word;`, to get the desired behavior.
Also, change `height` to `min-height`, so that the element resizes when necessary.
**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QhJWt/1/**

```
span
{
    min-height:20px;
    width:100px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple actually:

```
span
{
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```